# Expressing the summation $1-2-3-4-5..$ using strictly only one summation operator, in the simplest way possible.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation

My friend got me on this question of writing the summation, using strictly one summation operator only. So;

$$\sum_{k=0}^n x = 1-2-3-4-5-...$$

So in here what will be the most simplest function or expression for $x$ suitable to get the result? Note that no

> $1+\sum_{k=2}^n-k$

or similar expression is allowed as it has a part that is not under a summation operator. This has been a challenge to me honestly. While my work on this was this;

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\frac{3}{2}-k}{\sqrt{{(\frac{3}{2}-k)}^2}}k = 1-2-3-4-5-...$$

This also kinda looks not neat, I'm also trying to tone it down, so any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you need everything under the sum? The $1-\sum_{k \geq 2}k$ seems perfectly simple to me. Putting everything under the sum makes it only more complicated.

Comment: Again? This question was asked twice recently, and not very well received... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3346330/a-way-to-write-1-2-3-4-5-n-exclusively-using-summation-only (deleted), https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345909/what-will-be-the-summation-expression-so-as-to-get-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-n

Answer (score 1):

What about $$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{2^k+1}(k+1)?$$

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of $1$ followed by $-1$ is [A153881](https://oeis.org/A153881), from there you can construct your sum for example as
\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{k = 1}^n (1 - 2\cdot \text{sgn}(k-1))\cdot  k \\
&=\sum_{k = 1}^n (-1)^{\text{sgn}(k-1)}\cdot  k \\
&=\sum_{k = 1}^n \left(2\left\lfloor\frac{1}{k}\right\rfloor-1\right)\cdot  k \\
&=\sum_{k = 1}^n (-1)^{p_k}  k
\end{align}
where $\text{sgn}(x)$ is a [Sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) and $p_n$ is $n$-th prime.

Comment: ah pretty close, you used primes here. Here's my another take on this; $$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k!-1}*k = 1-2-3-4-5...$$ In the prime number sequence, only $a(1)$ is divisible by 2, the rest are odd numbers. Same here with the factorials. Only $1!$ is odd, while the rest are even.

Answer (score 0):

How about with the use of the Unit step function centered at 2:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{u_2(k)}\cdot k$$

Answer (score 0):

A variation on $\left(2\lfloor\frac 1k\rfloor-1\right)k$ from [Sil's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3347129/399263).

This one can also be $(2\cdot0^k−1)$ upon the convention $0^0=1$. (or you can use $\delta_0(k)$ instead).

Note that $(-1)^{\delta_0(k)}$ offers also the same kind of alternative.

We could also put everything inside the floor function:
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\left\lfloor\frac{1-3k-2k^2}{2k+1}\right\rfloor$$